# How is it possible to split a string by whitespaces, and also keep commas separate?

Tags: javascript, regex, split, regular-language

I would like to break up a sentence into words. If it only contains whitespaces, then `.split(/\s+/)` works.

But how is it possible to split by comma as well, and also keep the comma in the resulting array?

I tried something like this, but it does not work:

```
.split(/(?=,)|(?!=,)|\s/)
```

Example input:

```
"this,is, a test"
```

Expected output:

```
["this", ",", "is", ",", "a", "test"]
```

What do I wrong? Is it even possible using regex only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```js
console.log(
  "this,is, a test".match(/[^\s,]+|,/g)
)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7v1uJU/1).

The `String#match` method with a regex featuring the `g` modifier extracts all non-overlapping occurrences of

- `[^\s,]+` - any one or more chars other than whitespace (`\s`) and a comma
- `|` - or
- `,` - a comma.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to split on whitespaces and keep the comma's, another option could be to match 1+ whitespace chars or capture the comma in a capturing group to keep it and remove the empty entries.

```
(,)|\s+
```

- `(,)` Capture a comma in group 1 to keep using split
- `|` Or
- `\s+` Match 1 or more whitespace chars

```js
console.log(
  "this,is, a test"
  .split(/(,)|\s+/)
  .filter(Boolean)
);
```